# How to use scanf in for loop

Tags: c, input, formatting, scanf

Whenever i try to read input with

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    scanf("(%c, %d, %d, %d)",&charv,&intv1,&intv2,&intv3);
}
```

I only get to `scanf()` once. What is the problem ?

Input -> (P, 1, 2, 3)......(P, 2, 3, 12)

Comment: I hope that in your actual code you have actual variables as arguments, and not types. And unless you post *actual* and working code, together with the input, we will not really be able to help you.

Comment: Messages? Exceptions? Is one of your variables `i`?

Comment: Yes i do have actual variables the types were just a place holders.Also this is the actual code....

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that makes existing comments and answers invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of `scanf()` is wrong. You have to provide the **pointer to the variable** to store the value read by `scanf()`. You need to use it like below

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    scanf("%c, %d, %d, %d",&charVar,&intvar1,&intVar2,&intVar3);
}
```

---

EDIT:

Point 1: The supplied *format string* should **exactly** match with the input. Otherwise, `scanf()` will fail. If your input is not of format `(<char>, <int>....` , it will fail. Either of missing `(`, `)`, `,` will cause mismatch in the supplied format string with the input and make `scanf()` to stop scanning. It's strongly recommended to check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure it's success.

Point 2: To avoid reading the `\n` stored by previous ENTER<\kbd> key press, you should add a leading space before `%c`. So, you can use something like

```
scanf(" %c, %d, %d, %d",&charVar,&intvar1,&intVar2,&intVar3);
       ^
       |
     Notice here
```

Comment: the int, char, char, char are only placeholders i have  actual variables in the real code

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("(%c, %d, %d, %d)",&charvar,&intvar1,&intvar2,&intvar3);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c, %d, %d, %d",&charvar,&intvar1,&intvar2,&intvar3);
```

Note the space before `%c` which ignores newline if it exists. If your input is not separated by commas

```
scanf(" %c %d %d %d",&charvar,&intvar1,&intvar2,&intvar3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Sourav Ghosh and Gopi said, scanf will not work properly with this syntax

```
scanf("(%c, %d, %d, %d)",&char,&int,&int,&int);
```

It should be

```
scanf("%c %d %d %d",&char,&int,&int,&int);
```

But you can read a string first, and then use sscanf.

Try this code:

```
char ch;
int a, b, c, i;

char teste[256];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    fgets(teste, 256, stdin);
    sscanf(teste, "(%c, %d, %d, %d)", &ch, &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%c %d %d %d\n", ch, a, b, c);
}
```